# LaTeX math mode ($...$) font color in org mode

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I have just started using org-mode and it looks awesome. The only issue that I have so far is that when I write a text in mathmode `($...$)` it appears in the standard-text font color.

So, I would like to make org-mode to identify the mathmode text and be able to present it in some other color. Note that I don't need to change the color of the actual equation, just the source text in org-mode.

Here is an example of how the text is currently presented

> A paper by Rohnert, titled "Moving a disc between polygons" introduces
>   a structure using which one can generate  a solution (path) for
>   a given query in $O(\log n) + k$ time.

and how I would like it to look

> A paper by Rohnert, titled "Moving a disc between polygons" introduces
>   a structure using which one can generate  a solution (path) for
>   a given query in **$O(\log n) + k$** time.

(Note that I would prefer to display in some given color, e.g. red, and not bold face.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Emacs version 24.4 and later, this is controlled via the variable `org-highlight-latex-and-related`:

> Non-nil means highlight LaTeX related syntax in the buffer. When non
>   nil, the value should be a list containing any of the following
>   symbols:
>
> - `latex'    Highlight LaTeX snippets and environments.
> - `script'   Highlight subscript and superscript.
> - `entities' Highlight entities.

So something like

```
(eval-after-load 'org
  '(setf org-highlight-latex-and-related '(latex)))
```

in your init should help. Such code is formatted according to the face `org-latex-and-related`.

In earlier versions, the variable `org-highlight-latex-fragments-and-specials`, which is a simpler nil / non-nil variable:

```
(eval-after-load 'org
  '(setf org-highlight-latex-fragments-and-specials t))
```

In this case, the face `org-latex-and-export-specials` is used.